# RichFaces Drop down menu links to work in target panel

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I new to RichFaces and have been tinkering with it for a few days, I was playing around with drop down menus and i can only see examples of rendering text when a tab is clicked, what i am looking for is to renderer a page when clicking a link in the drop down menu.

Any pointers or help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<rich:menuItem value="Menu item text" action="targetNavigationCaseOutcome" />
```

In the `action` attribute you can specify a value defined in `faces-config.xml` as an outcome to a navigation case. The same way as you do for a simple `<h:commandLink>` or `<h:commandButton>`.